# What other galaxies can be seen with the naked eye in the night sky?

Tags: galaxy

What other galaxies can be seen with the naked eye in the night sky? Can we see any other galaxy besides Andromeda and Magellanic Clouds?

Answer (score 4):

We can see the Magellenic clouds easily, and we can see Andromeda on very dark, clear nights, but only when we are far from the city.

Some people claim to have seen the Triangulum galaxy (the third largest member of the local group, after Andromeda and the Milky way). Exceptional conditions, and very well trained eyes would be required to see it.

No other galaxies are visible, even under the best conditions.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://starchild.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/StarChild/questions/question15.html) the main galaxy you can see besides the milky way is Andromeda. However, the Large and Small Magellanic clouds can be southern hemisphere.

To find Andromeda, Start at the northeast corner of the Great Square of Pagasus - the constellation Andromeda forms a "handle" attached to the northeast corner of the "bowl" formed by the Great Square. Find the second bright star in the handle (the last star before the end of the handle) and from that star, make a 90 degree turn to the line that joins the two handle stars, pass the first star you see and look at the 2nd "star". It appears to be a "fuzzy star". That is the Andromeda Galaxy. (Source: See above)

A chart to help you!

[image]

You'll probably need a telescope to view other galaxies. Other than that, that is pretty much it!